# How to get manifest permissions of any installed Android app

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Is it possible to get the manifest permissions of any installed Android application?

Comment: Do you want them programmatically?

Comment: Why do you need other app permissions ?How can i know providers application permissions ? so that i can define in my manifest file to  access there data

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks for the hint,got it running with:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

for (Object obj : pkgAppsList) {
  ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) obj;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
  try {
    packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Get installed packages using this.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

And use the package name to get the info.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have apk file it is very simple just open cmd from start menu and write this command line:

```
aapt d permissions D:\dina\app-debug.apk
```

take care for the path you write then you can get list from all permissions in this application and package name also like this:

```
package: com.example.dinasaif.facebookintegration
uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
```