# How to tell if an app has used certain permission in its manifest?

Tags: android

For example, I'm developing an app "A", and I want to use some codes in "A" to tell me if another app "B" has asked for "RECORD_AUDIO" permission in its manifest?

Who can give me those codes？ Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use PackageManager. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386823/how-to-get-manifest-permissions-of-any-installed-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getPackageManager().getPackageInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get a [`PackageInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html) object, from which you can get the permissions.