# Retrieving all kinds of permissions of the installed apps on Android device?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, permissions, android-permissions

All
I want to know how can I code an app that scans and retrieves all the permission of the installed apps on Android?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Have a look at PackageManager.getInstalledPackages and read up on PackageInfo.  This should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

for (Object obj : pkgAppsList) {
  ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) obj;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
  try { 
    packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
}
```

Source: [How to get manifest permissions of any installed Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386823/how-to-get-manifest-permissions-of-any-installed-android-app)